# make entire list to string in erlang

Tags: string, list, erlang

I'm trying to do the following

```
S = lists:concat(A) ++ " " ++ [254,874] ++ "\n".
```

it gives me error message

```
** exception error: no match of right hand side value [51,50,52,51,53,54,53,54,55,54,54,53,52,51,32,254,874,10]
```

but it works fine for string values "[254,874]"

how can I make [254,874] to "[254,874]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You maybe forgot `f(S)` for previous calculation. Try it before using your command:

```
1> f(S).
ok
2> S = lists:concat(A) ++ " " ++ [254,874] ++ "\n".
```

Moreover, you can use `$[` or `$]` for indicate `"[" "]"` in ASCII

```
3> $[.
91
4> $].
93
5> S = lists:concat(A) ++ " " ++ [91,254,874,93] ++ "\n".
```

Answer (score -1):

found the answer

```
A = [254,876].
lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~p",[A])).
```

this gives exact result 
    "[254,876]"

Answer (score -1):

To convert list of integers to string

for your case I would have done:

```
[A, B] = [254,876],
C = "[" ++ integer_to_list(A) ++ "," ++ integer_to_list(B) ++ "]".
```

for a more generic case:

```
-module(l2s).
-compile(export_all).

list_to_string([H|List]) ->
    list_to_string(List, "[" ++ integer_to_list(H)).

list_to_string([], String) -> String ++ "]";

list_to_string([H | List], String) ->
    list_to_string(List, String ++ "," ++ integer_to_list(H)).
```

Test:

```
Eshell V7.3  (abort with ^G)
1> A = [1,2,3,4,5].
[1,2,3,4,5]
2> l2s:list_to_string(A).
"[1,2,3,4,5]"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
"["++lists:concat(lists:join(",",A))++"]".
```

```
"[1,2,3,4]"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues.